# JPA Exception Handling in Spring WebApp

Tags: java, spring, jpa

I am working on a Spring web application having DAO, Service, Controller, View layers. JPA is being used for database access. The approach that I am using for JPA exception handling is as below.

```
public class DBException extends RuntimeException {
   implemented constructors to call appropriate RuntimeException constructors.
}

public MyDAOClass {
   public void save(Object object) {
       try {
           entityManager.persist(object);
       }catch(PersistenceException e) {
           throw new DBException("Error occurred in save", e);
       }
   }
}

public class MyServiceClass {
    public void serviceMethod() {
        dao.save(object);
    }
}

public class MyRestController {
    public void controllerMethod() {
        service.save();
    }
    @ExceptionHandler(DBException.class)
    public String handleDBException(DBException e, HttpServletRequest req) {
        implemented code to log & handle exception.
    }

}
```

I wanted to have more information in the exception, that's the reason to create custom DBException and also I don't wanted to propagate PersistenceException to other layers.

1. Is this correct approach for exception handling ?
2. Should I log the exception in all layers or logging it at the end at controller is good ?
3. I am catching `PersistenceException` and rethrowing `DBException`. Since `DBException` is a `RuntimeException` I think spring transaction should rollback in event of exception ?

Thanks.

Comment: I believe you might want to log exception in each layer and then throw it albeit it's RunTimeException

Comment: @NeilStockton It is just a pseudo code. I have updated it.

Comment: @AnantLaxmikantBobde Logging in each layer will have multiple log entries for same exception. That's the reason I have logged it in rest controller or should I do it in the DAO itself ?

Comment: althogh it creates multiple log entries it will provide a great information about the code flow and errors occurring in each layer I would still go with logging in each layer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this correct approach for exception handling ?

Yes, you should never propagate exceptions that are specific to layer to the layer above it. If you are expecting the clients of the data layer to recuperate from the exception then create a new custom checked exception and throw it from the catch block in save method.

> Should I log the exception in all layers or logging it at the end at
>   controller is good ?

Logging should be done only at one place, since logging at multiple levels can confuse the programmer examining the stack trace about the original source of exception. In this case I think its best to log the SQLException in the catch block of save method, since you are rethrowing a RuntimeException, the caller of save method may not necessarily catch the exception and log it.

> I am catching PersistenceException and rethrowing DBException. Since
>   DBException is a RuntimeException I think spring transaction should
>   rollback in event of exception ?

Yes, Spring transactions rollback in case of RuntimeException. This is because the caller code cannot do much in case of RuntimeException, since it represents unrecoverable condition. This behaviour is defined in the [Docs](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html#transaction-declarative-attransactional-settings).

More about best practices for exception handling [here](http://www.onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/2003/11/19/exceptions.html?page=2)

Comment: So it seems it's better to log exception in the DAO itself where I am catching the PersistenceException. But if the caller of the save method catches the exception & logs it that will duplicate the exception log. But I guess that how it is ? Thanks for the answer.